# Help needed on nested web User Control event in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Scenario: I have a nested web user controls in my asp web page, and I have a button inside the child user control.

Web Page: references a parent control called “slot” which dynamically loads

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Home.aspx.cs" 
 Inherits="light.Home" %>

<%@ Reference Control="~/UserControl/Slot.ascx" %>
```

Parent User Control: references a child control called “ray” which also dynamically loads

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Slot.ascx.cs"    
 Inherits="light.Slot" %>

<%@ Reference Control="~/UserControl/Ray.ascx" %>
```

Child User Control: has a button called “ButtonRay” which i want it to run on its click event.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Ray.ascx.cs" 
 Inherits="light.Ray" %>

<div id="AddRay" runat="server">

<asp:Button ID="ButtonRay" runat="server" Text="Ray" 
onclick="ButtonRay_Click"/>


</div>
```

**Problem: The button does not fire its click event (ButtonRay_Click) from the server side**

```
protected void ButtonComment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // this the code that i want to be executed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's just me, but I've never seen controls referenced and loaded like that.  Here's what I would try doing it this way (which works for me):

In your Home page, register your Slot control like this instead of referencing it like your were before:

```
<%@ Register TagName="Slot" TagPrefix="cc" Src="~/Slot.ascx" %>
```

And then add the control to your page with:

```
<cc:Slot ID="SlotControl" runat="server" />
```

Now in Slot.ascx, register and include the Ray control:

```
<%@ Register TagName="Ray" TagPrefix="cc" Src="~/Ray.ascx" %>

<cc:Ray ID="RayControl" runat="server" />
```

And now in your Ray control, add your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="ButtonRay" Text="Ray" OnClick="ButtonRay_OnClick" runat="server" />
```

And in the Ray.ascx.cs code-behind, add your event handler:

```
protected void ButtonRay_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

When I add a break-point on this method, run the app, and click the button, the OnClick event is caught like it should be.  I think what's happening is that merely referencing your controls doesn't wire up the events.  If you were dynamically loading your controls, you have to use `Page.LoadControl()` so that it wires up correctly.

Let me know if you need more explanation.

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that your button click method name was not the same as the one your were asking it to call:  you have the ButtonRay button doing ButtonRay_Click, but the name of your method is ButtonComment_Click.

Comment: When you register your user control, you can only see a single instance of thatcontrol in the webpage. However, if you use the reference declarative, you can have as many instances as you like (
slot = (Slot)LoadControl("~/UserControl/Slot.ascx")). that is why i used references. thanks

Comment: If you use LoadControl you don't even need to reference it.  And I can register a control and use it however many times I want (e.g. a custom Button or Hyperlink control).  It would be pretty useless if you couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0):

### in aspx Page.ie: Home.aspx.cs

override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)

```
{
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}
```

private Button GetButton()

```
{


    Button Btn = (Button)SlotControl.FindControl("RayControl").FindControl("ButtonRay");
    return Btn;
}



private void InitializeComponent()
{


    /*   For button Event Initialization */

    Button Btnclk = GetButton();

    Btnclk.Click += new EventHandler(Btnclk_TextChanged);

}
```

void Btnclk_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
```

/* write ur code here.............*/

```
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

### in aspx Page.

override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.OnInit(e);
    }
 private Button GetButton()
    {
        Button Btn = (Button)SlotControl.FindControl("RayControl").FindControl("ButtonRay");
        return Btn;
    }
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        /*   For button Event Initialization */

```
    Button Btnclk = GetButton();

    Btnclk.Click += new EventHandler(Btnclk_TextChanged);
```

}
 void Btnclk_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
{
```

/* write ur code here.............*/

}